# MATCH produces identical result if multiple matchs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2010, excel-2016

Working on automating sections of a spreadsheet I use for work and can't seem to solve this issue.

https://imgur.com/a/nq3RGLv

On the left I have I have the lane number and count per lane. On the right I want to have the top 6 highest numbers and there respective lanes.

I grab the highest 6 numbers using `=LARGE(B2:B19, 1)` all the way through to `=LARGE(B2:B19, 6)` and insert them on the right.

The issue that I have is when I use MATCH in the left column of TOP 6 to label the highest numbers.

At the moment I am using `="LANE "&MATCH(E2,B2:B19,0)` in the left cells to say LANE 10 7 6 etc BUT if there are two identical numbers on the right it just says the same lane twice.

So in my photo, D4 should say LANE 9 not 4.

Whats the optimal way to correct this issue? Perhaps theres a simpler function for this? Prefereably something that will work in slightly older versions as well, I'm on 2016 at the moment.

I truly appreciate any help I can get. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula in D2

```
="Lane"&" "&SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$19=E2,ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2)+1),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2))
```

This will work in excel 2016 and let me know if there is something that you don t understand in this formula so i will explain you

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative approach using <kbd>AGGREGATE( )</kbd> Function which is available since Excel 2010+ onwards.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(E2="","","LANE "&AGGREGATE(15,7,$A$2:$A$19/(E2=$B$2:$B$19),COUNTIFS(E$2:E2,E2)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=IF(ROWS(E$1:E1)>6,"",AGGREGATE(14,7,$B$2:$B$19/($A$2:$A$19<>""),ROW($ZZ1)))
```

---

However, it will be easier to do in `MS365`

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK("LANE "&A2:A19,B2:B19),2,-1),6)
```

---